# Why does co-occurrence matrix have 0 values in diagonal?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

I am studying this [document](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/lecture_notes/LectureNotes1.pdf) but I can't understand why in the [word-word co occurrence matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-occurrence) the terms in the diagonal are all 0. Or in other words why I do not count the word itself in the co-occurrence matrix?

Comment: What led you to believe that it is all zeros on the diagonal?

Comment: http://cs224d.stanford.edu/lecture_notes/LectureNotes1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In the example that you linked in your comment none of the sentences use the same word twice. If they did then that word would co-occur with itself and there would be an entry on the diagonal. So, it's just a coincidence that the diagonal is all zeros in the example you saw.

Comment: Thank you. I understand your point of view, but my question is a little bit different, why I do not count the word itself in the co occurrence matrix?

Comment: Because that gives you very little information about the meaning of the word. what you are trying to capture is the relationship of a word to other words